# R, colbycol can't load a file

Tags: r

I have a file that can be readed by `read.table` method. File is near 500M sized. but when I try to read it using package [colbycol](http://colbycol.r-forge.r-project.org/), I get an error.

```
Error in .jnew("com/datanalytics/colbycol/ColByCol", file, paste(lapply(columns,  : 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the example from the `colbycol` package tutorial? Sounds like an error with your java installation.

Comment: I have tried test example from tutorial, all works fine.

Comment: I have the same problem except that, no, I can't run the test example. How can I find out what the problem is with my java installation?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried reading in a csv file. Specifying the separator fixed it for me though. Just to be clear:

```
data <- cbc.read.table("file.csv", just.read = c(1,4,7), sep = ",")
df <- as.data.frame(data)
```

Hope this helps.